# Layout possible? Flexbox vs Float layout with multiple columns and rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm curious if this layout is possible with flexbox. I can't seem to work out divs 3 & 4 to fall under #2. This is pretty easy with floats, just curious if I'm missing some properties that may help with flexbox.

**Layout**

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| div 1 |     div 2     |
+       +-------+-------+
|       | div 3 | div 4 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="features">
  <div class="feature feature-1">1</div>
  <div class="feature feature-2">2</div>
  <div class="feature feature-3">3</div>
  <div class="feature feature-4">4</div>
</div>
```

**Demo**

http://codepen.io/mikevoermans/pen/xbWvJJ?editors=110

Comment: So, you have fixed html, but want to change css to layout it?

Comment: @Vanuan Not exactly, just wanted to know if the layout was possible with this simplified markup. However at this point, the project has launched, using floats instead. Just hoped to take advantage of fluid heights leveraging flexbox in some way.

Comment: I think it's better to have several containers and change flex-direction several times.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use Grid layout:
http://gridbyexample.com/what/

Flexbox is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Flexbox does not like flex items that expand through multiple columns or rows, because in fact flexbox has no grid notion.

However, using some tricks, you can achieve this layout (and [more complicated ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30489151/1529630) too):

- Use a row layout

  ```
  ┌─┬─┬─┬─┐
  │1│2│3│4│
  └─┴─┴─┴─┘
  ```
- Allow line breaks with `flex-wrap: wrap`.
- Use a pseudo element to force a line break after 2

  ```
  ┌─┬─┐
  │1│2│
  ├─┼─┤
  │3│4│
  └─┴─┘
  ```
- Use `flex: 1` on all flex items.

  ```
  ┌─────────┬─────────┐
  │1        │2        │
  ├─────────┼─────────┤
  │3        │4        │
  └─────────┴─────────┘
  ```
- Set `margin-left: 50%` to 3

  ```
  ┌─────────┬─────────┐
  │1        │2        │
  └─────────┼────┬────┤
            │3   │4   │
            └────┴────┘
  ```
- Set `height: 200px`, to 2, 3 and 4. Set `height: 400px` to 1.

  ```
  ┌─────────┬─────────┐
  │1        │2        │
  │         ├─────────┘
  │         │
  └─────────┼────┬────┐
            │3   │4   │
            └────┴────┘
  ```
- Set `margin-bottom: -200px` to 1:

  ```
  ┌─────────┬─────────┐
  │1        │2        │
  │         ├────┬────┤
  │         │3   │4   │
  └─────────┴────┴────┘
  ```
- Since you have borders, use `box-sizing: border-box` on all boxes to make `height` include the borders. Otherwise 1 would need `height: 416px; margin-bottom: -216px`.
- Note flexbox introduces `auto` as the new initial value of `min-width`. That could allow the content to force some boxes to grow. That would break the layout, so disable it with `min-width: 0` or setting `overflow` to anything but `visible`.

Here is the code:

```css
.features {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.feature {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
.feature-1 {
  /* Make it taller without increasing the height of the flex line */
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}
.features:after {
  /* Force line break */
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}
.feature-2 ~ .feature {
  /* Place 3 and 4 after the line break */
  order: 1;
}
.feature-3 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
  <div class="feature feature-1">1</div>
  <div class="feature feature-2">2</div>
  <div class="feature feature-3">3</div>
  <div class="feature feature-4">4</div>
</div>
```

However, it would be easier to modify the HTML in order to have nested flexboxes.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 400px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex > div {
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
.item {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="flex row">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="flex column">
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="flex row">
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with flexbox, but possible with CSS Grid.
It's not yet shipped with all major browsers, but there's a polyfill:

https://jsfiddle.net/hvdq63ah/

```css
.features {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "feature1 feature2 feature2"
      "feature1 feature3 feature4";
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(min-content, 1fr) minmax(min-content, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto minmax(min-content, 1fr);      
      
  background-color: #fff;
}

.feature-1    { grid-area: feature1 }
.feature-2    { grid-area: feature2 }
.feature-3    { grid-area: feature3 }
.feature-4    { grid-area: feature4 }

.feature {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
  <div class="feature feature-1">1</div>
  <div class="feature feature-2">2</div>
  <div class="feature feature-3">3</div>
  <div class="feature feature-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right around the corner from this being supported/shipped now. Thanks for your answer. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: @mikevoermans yeah, I have Chrome 57 and the snipped above is displayed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible and easy with flexbox to achieve the layout by employing three flex containers.

1. The main flex container `#rFlex` wraps everything into a row.
2. The vertical right is wrapped in `#cFlex` causing `#flex2, #flex3`, and `#flex4` to flow in a column.
3. Then the flex items `#flex3` and `#flex4` are set to flow horizontally by `#sFlex`.
4. `#cflex` is `inline-flex` so that it can stay solidly next to `#flex1`

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
body {
  background: #121;
  color: #FEF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
/* Flex Containers */

#rFlex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
}
#cflex {
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 45vw;
}
#sFlex {
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
/* Flex Items */

.flex {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#flex1 {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: red;
}
#flex2 {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background: blue;
}
#flex3,
#flex4 {
  width: 22.5vw;
  height: 40vh;
}
#flex3 {
  background: yellow;
}
#flex4 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<main id="rFlex">
  <section id="flex1" class="flex">

  </section>
  <article id="cFlex">
    <section id="flex2" class="flex">

    </section>
    <aside id="sFlex">
      <section id="flex3" class="flex">

      </section>
      <section id="flex4" class="flex">

      </section>
    </aside>
  </article>
</main>
```