# Have certain items stack along the cross axis within a row/column of a flex layout with only CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

At one point I was toying with a CSS spec suggestion for this, but then I figured there is probably already a solution that I am missing. An example of the kind of layout I'm talking about would look something like this:

```
+-----------+---+
|     1     | 6 |
+---+---+---+   |
| 2 | 3 | 4 +---+
+---+---+---+ 7 |
|     5     |   |
+-----------+---+
```

The problem is those three boxes in the middle of the left column are stacked along the cross axis, and I can't find a mechanism in CSS to do this. I know this could be done with a div wrapped around those 3 items that is a row direction flex layout, but that approach breaks the flexibility of a flex layout because those items can no longer be re-ordered around the outer layout and a column/row break can no longer happen between them. So, how can this be achieved this with only CSS, so that the flex layout stays flexable?

HTML:

```
<div id="flex-layout">
<div id="item1">1</div>
<div id="item2">2</div>
<div id="item3">3</div>
<div id="item4">4</div>
<div id="item5">5</div>
<div id="item6">6</div>
<div id="item7">7</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#flex-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#item1 {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

#item2 {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#item3 {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#item4 {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#item5 {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#item6 {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    width: 100px;
}

#item7 {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have written so far please?

Comment: That was just a mock up of a hypothetical case, but I added some code for it.

Comment: If you don't mind placing 6 and 7 in another flex container, you can use a row layout.

Comment: @Oriol I know that that is an option as well, but I'd like to avoid editing the HTML at all in order to preserve the spirit of flex layouts, otherwise it seems like a shortcoming in the current flex layout specification. If it is in fact a shortcoming in the current spec, then I have an idea I was toying with that might resolve that shortcoming, but I want to make sure I'm not glossing over an existing solution somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone happens to come across this now a days, a less hack-ish way to achieve this sort of layout is the newer grid layout system. Grids are more designed for this kind of layout while flex is more suited for distributing items in a single row/column (including things like vertically centering elements) or when items are inconsistent sizes along the flex axis and lining them up with each other across multiple rows/columns isn't a concern.

```css
#grid-layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    /* 4 columns each 25% width - 3/4 of an em for the grid-gap */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25% - (3em / 4))); 
    grid-template-rows: 10em 4.5em 4.5em 10em;
}

#grid-layout > div {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: .5em;
}

#item1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 3; }
#item2 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 2 / span 1; }
#item3 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / span 2 / span 1; }
#item4 { grid-area: 2 / 3 / span 2 / span 1; }
#item5 { grid-area: 4 / 1 / span 1 / span 3; }
#item6 { grid-area: 1 / 4 / span 2 / span 1; }
#item7 { grid-area: 3 / 4 / span 2 / span 1; }
```

```html
<div id="grid-layout">
    <div id="item1">1</div>
    <div id="item2">2</div>
    <div id="item3">3</div>
    <div id="item4">4</div>
    <div id="item5">5</div>
    <div id="item6">6</div>
    <div id="item7">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Using multiple flex containers would be easier.

But if you want a single container, you can still do it, with those assumptions:

- The width of 6 and 7 is known
- The height of 2, 3 and 4 is known

Then, you can

- Use a row layout

  ```
  ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
  │1│2│3│4│5│6│7│
  └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
  ```
- Reorder the flex items: 1,6,2,3,4,5,7

  ```
  ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
  │1│6│2│3│4│5│7│
  └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
  ```
- Allow line breaks with `flex-wrap: wrap`.
- Use pseudo elements to force a line break before 2 and after 4

  ```
  ┌─┬─┐
  │1│6│
  ├─┼─┼─┐
  │2│3│4│
  ├─┼─┼─┘
  │5│7│
  └─┴─┘
  ```
- Use `flex-grow: 0` on 6 and 7. Use `flex-grow: 1` on the other ones.

  ```
  ┌─────────┬─┐
  │    1    │6│
  ├───┬───┬─┴─┤
  │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │
  ├───┴───┴─┬─┤
  │    5    │7│
  └─────────┴─┘
  ```
- Set the desired with, `w`, to 6 and 7. Add `margin-right: w` to 4

  ```
  ┌─────┬───┐
  │  1  │ 6 │
  ├─┬─┬─┼───┘
  │2│3│4│
  ├─┴─┴─┼───┐
  │  5  │ 7 │
  └─────┴───┘
  ```
- Set the desired height, `h`, to 2, 3 and 4. Add `margin-bottom: -h/2` to 6, and `margin-top: -h/2` to 7.

  ```
  ┌─────┬───┐
  │  1  │ 6 │
  ├─┬─┬─┤   │
  │2│3│4├───┤
  ├─┴─┴─┤ 7 │
  │  5  │   │
  └─────┴───┘
  ```
- Additionally, it might be a good idea adding a `width` or `max-width` to 2,3,4. Otherwise, if their content is wide enough, they will be placed in different lines, breaking the layout.

Here is the code:

```css
#flex-layout {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Multiline */
}
#item1 { order: 1; }
#item6 { order: 2; }
#item2 { order: 3; }
#item3 { order: 4; }
#item4 { order: 5; }
#item5 { order: 6; }
#item7 { order: 7; }
#flex-layout > div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#item2, #item3, #item4 {
  height: 50px; /* h */
}
#item6 {
  margin-bottom: -25px; /* -h/2 */
}
#item7 {
  margin-top: -25px; /* -h/2 */
}
#item1, #item2, #item3, #item4, #item5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#item6, #item7 {
  width: 25%; /* w */
  flex-grow: 0;
}
#item4 {
  margin-right: 25%; /* w */
}
#flex-layout:before {
  /* Force line break before #item2 */
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  order: 3;
}
#flex-layout:after {
  /* Force line break after #item4 */
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  order: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-layout">
  <div id="item1">1</div>
  <div id="item2">2</div>
  <div id="item3">3</div>
  <div id="item4">4</div>
  <div id="item5">5</div>
  <div id="item6">6</div>
  <div id="item7">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but it seems like a hack and probably wouldn't work in every situation. It seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: @sigilbaram Well, flexible items can flow in columns or in rows. If you want a mix of those without adding more flex containers, you must use tricks like this. Otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses absolute position.

```css
#flex-layout {
  border: 4px solid tomato;  
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
}
#flex-layout div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}
#flex-layout #item1 {
  flex: 0 1 75%;
  margin-right: 25%;  
}
#flex-layout #item5 {
  flex: 0 1 75%;
}
#flex-layout #item6 {
  width: 25%; height: 50%;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0; right: 0;
}
#flex-layout #item7 {
  width: 25%; height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 0;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div id="flex-layout">
      <div id="item1">1</div>
      <div id="item2">2</div>
      <div id="item3">3</div>
      <div id="item4">4</div>
      <div id="item5">5</div>
      <div id="item6">6</div>
      <div id="item7">7</div>
    </div>
```