# Unequal row heights in a flex column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to make a layout like the picture below but I don't know how to specify the column to make it be like a part of it 3/4 the column and the other part is 1/4, I'm trying to use flexbox

This what I want the layout looks like:

[image]

I don't know how to make what I'm saying up there :D as am still new to flexbox.

but down below my attempt to create this thing, but i couldn't make the first column consists of two unequal rows.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45vw;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 25px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "cmd  grph grph grph  " 
    "write grph grph grph";
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row;*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.dot {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.command {
  grid-area: cmd;
}

#grph {
  grid-area: grph;
}

#write {
  grid-area: write;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="command box"></div>
  <div id="grph" class="box"></div>
  <div id="write" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Baron14/pen/YzwqBVM I created this pen here demonstrating how to use flexbox for your current need. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot

Comment: Note a couple of syntax errors in your code. `fr` should be `1fr` (or whatever value you want). `#cmd` grid area applying to container, so it won't work. Also there's no `.dot` element.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thank you, updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(2,fr);
}
```

If you want two grid areas split 3/4 and 1/4, then why use two rows? Use four rows instead.

### Grid

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 45vw;
  gap: 25px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "cmd  grph grph grph  "
    "cmd  grph grph grph  "
    "cmd  grph grph grph  "    
    "write grph grph grph";
}

.command  { grid-area: cmd; }
#grph     { grid-area: grph;  }
#write    { grid-area: write; }

.box      { border: 5px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="cmd">
  <div class="command box"></div>
  <div id="grph" class="box"></div>
  <div id="write" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Flex

Here's the flexbox solution:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 45vw;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.command {
  flex: 3;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#grph {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: 1;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#write {
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="cmd">
  <div class="command box"></div>
  <div id="grph" class="box"></div>
  <div id="write" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you control the size of the column in the flex solution ?

Comment: @AdhamNawito a *compact* version of the CSS grid solution if you are intrested: https://jsfiddle.net/bnmsqLt9/1/ .. not easy to deal with but it can give ideas of optimization if you will be having a more complex template.

Answer (score 0):

first of all give class name different of
 `class="box1"`
after that change its property

```
box1{
height:40vh
}

box2{
height: 20vh}
```