# Align flex items with different heights in the same container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wonder if it's possible to get flex items horizontally aligned to larger flex items in the same container. Using CSS floats it would be easily accomplished, but I haven't been able to get it done with flex items.

[View this JSFiddle for a flexbox example.](https://jsfiddle.net/vc00cbLu/1/)

[View this JSFiddle a float example](https://jsfiddle.net/tp7dp1kL/2/)

*Grid layout*

```
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="large-flex-item">
</div>
<div class="small-flex-item">
 </div>
<div class="small-flex-item">
 </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
 .flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: flex-start;
   max-width: 500px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
 }

 .small-flex-item {
   flex-basis: 33.333%;
   background: #000;
   padding-top: 30%;
 }

 .large-flex-item {
   flex-basis: 66.667%;
   background: #333;
   padding-top: 60%;
 }
```

Comment: I think it might be because you are wrapping to the next line - have you tried removing wrap?

Comment: If you want a row layout this isn't possible with flexbox unless you wrap the smaller elements in their own container. It's possible if you use column layout though....but that has it's own issues.

Comment: I see multiple differences between the fiddles, but they don't seem to match the description of the question. Are you talking about percentage in vertical padding being resolved relatively to height instead of width (and thus becoming 0)? Are you talking about stacking some flex items vertically inside a row?

Comment: @orial I'm talking about accomplishing the result of the float example with the flexbox example.

Comment: @Tim But the fiddles seem completely unrelated to horizontal alignment

Comment: @orial I might be using the wrong terminology, but might reasoning is: the last smaller item is currently positioned vertically opposed the large item, my goal is to position it horizontally to the large item. Feel free to edit the description if you think it can be done better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the layout by nesting flex containers.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="large-flex-item"></div><!-- flex item #1 -->

  <div class="flex-container-inner"><!-- flex item #2 & nested flex container -->
     <div class="small-flex-item"></div><!-- this flex item and sibling will align... -->
     <div class="small-flex-item"></div><!-- ... in column next to .large-flex-item -->
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .flex-container {
   display: flex;
   width: 500px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
 }

 .large-flex-item {
   flex-basis: 66.667%;
   height: 200px;
   background: #333;
 }

.flex-container-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.small-flex-item {
   flex-basis: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: #000;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vc00cbLu/3/)

Comment: Awesome, I need the items to be in the same container though ( I'm using jQuery sortable UI ), so I'm sticking with floats. But this does solve the question.

Answer (score 14):

Flexbox does not like flex items that expand through multiple columns or rows, because in fact flexbox has no grid notion.

However, using some tricks, you can achieve this layout (and [more complicated ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30489151/1529630) too):

- Use a row layout

  ```
  ┌─┬─┬─┐
  │1│2│3│
  └─┴─┴─┘
  ```
- Allow line breaks with `flex-wrap: wrap`.
- Use a pseudo element to force a line break after 2

  ```
  ┌─┬─┐
  │1│2│
  ├─┼─┘
  │3│
  └─┘
  ```
- Use `width: 33%` on 2 and 3, and `flex: 1` on 1.

  ```
  ┌───────────────┬─────┐
  │1              │2    │
  ├─────┬─────────┴─────┘
  │3    │
  └─────┘
  ```
- Set `margin-left: auto` to 3

  ```
  ┌───────────────┬─────┐
  │1              │2    │
  └───────────────┼─────┤
                  │3    │
                  └─────┘
  ```
- Choose some length `x`
- Set `height: x` to 2 and 3. Set `height: 2*x` to 1.

  ```
  ┌───────────────┬─────┐
  │1              │2    │
  │               ├─────┘
  │               │
  └───────────────┼─────┐
                  │3    │
                  └─────┘
  ```
- Set `margin-bottom: -x` to 1:

  ```
  ┌───────────────┬─────┐
  │1              │2    │
  │               ├─────┤
  │               │3    │
  └───────────────┴─────┘
  ```
- Note flexbox introduces `auto` as the new initial value of `min-width`. That could allow the content to force some boxes to grow. That would break the layout, so disable it with `min-width: 0` or setting `overflow` to anything but `visible`.

Here is the code:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%; /* Force line break */
}
.large.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  background: red;
}
.small.flex-item {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.small.flex-item + .small.flex-item {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="large flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="small flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="small flex-item">3</div>
</div>
```

However, it would be easier to modify the HTML in order to have nested flexboxes.

Comment: Really hacky but amazing diagrams!