# CSS Flexbox : How to construct a specific layout

Tags: css, flexbox, fluid-layout

Following divs have to be created using flexbox , on condition that 3 of them should be siblings ( can not use two wrappers for each column ).

Anyone have an idea how to make this using pure flex ?

[image: Flex]

My current trial:

**HTML:**

```
       <div class="meeting-room-wrap">
            <div class="observable-module">
            </div>
            <div class="observable-module">
            </div>
            <div class="active-module">
            </div>    
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.meeting-room-wrap
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row
}
.observable-module
{
    flex-grow:1;
    height: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
}
.observable-module:nth-child(1) /* div #1 */
{
        background: green;
        order : 1;

}
.observable-module:nth-child(2) /* div #3 */
{
        background: blue;
        order : 3;
}
.active-module  /* div #2 */
{
    flex-grow:1;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 50%;
    background: red;
    order : 2;

}
```

Comment: A wrapper for the left and the right side is not acceptable for you?

Comment: @purii unfortunately no

Comment: does `.meeting-room-wrap` have a fixed height?

Comment: @JamieBarker 100% height of the body

Comment: This does what you want (keeping all flex items as siblings): http://stackoverflow.com/a/34070156/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wrapped Left Column Option**

The left divs in a flex column would the the most obvious approach...*absent the given constraint*.

```css
.meeting-room-wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  background: #c0ffee;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.observable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.observable-module {
  flex: 1;
  background: #bada55;
}
.observable-module:nth-child(2) {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
.active-module {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="meeting-room-wrap">
  <div class="observable">
    <div class="observable-module">
    </div>
    <div class="observable-module">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="active-module">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Flex-column Option** ...no extra wrappers required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #c0ffee;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  color: red;
  Font-size: 36px;
}
.alpha,
.gamma {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #000;
}
.beta {
  background: #bada55;
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.gamma {
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="alpha">ONE
  </div>
  <div class="beta">TWO
  </div>
  <div class="gamma">THREE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read the question well : on condition that 3 of them should be siblings ( can not use two wrappers for each column ). Thank You

Comment: this is what the question is about.

Comment: @ProllyGeek I think giving downvote doesn't fix any problem.

Comment: @alirezasafian you should tell that to whoever downvoted the answer , as I didnt downvote it !

Comment: @alirezasafian I always appreciate whoever answers my questions , even if wrongly answered.

Comment: @Paulie_D Perfect Thank You

Comment: @ProllyGeek for 3 sibbling div, flex is useless but float would do and pseudos to give a ration to each boxes http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZOjzw

Comment: @GCyrillus very nice , you could this as answer.

Comment: @ProllyGeek okay i'll do that if it can usefull for somes.

Answer (score 1):

given that it has a fixed height, why not use positioning?

```css
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap > div {
  position: absolute;  
}
.one {
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}
.two {
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.three {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="small one">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="two large">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="three small">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because then it's not flexbox...is it?

Comment: @JamieBarker Thanks for your answer jamie , but I think Paulie's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'll point you to the second comment on your own answer, one which you wrote ;). "_Probably not possible with flexbox with that constraint...flexbox can't work miracles._"

Comment: @ProllyGeek I agree. I was [working on a flexbox solution](https://jsfiddle.net/fvgf7e0k/). Figured I would throw this answer into the pot if there wasn't one as technically it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

as requested, comment turned into an answer.

have fun with it :)

```css
.meeting-room-wrap {
  width: 70%;
  /* whatever */
  margin: auto;
}

.meeting-room-wrap>div {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-size:4vw;
}

.meeting-room-wrap>div:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 40%;/* tune this to get ratio needed */
  display:inline-block;/* contents of these 3 wrappers should be within an inline-block element */
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.meeting-room-wrap>div.two:before {
  padding-top: 80%;/* height's ratio x 2*/
}

.one {
  background: #4779A3;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  background: #212F3B;
  float: right;
}

.three {
  background: #9BA1A3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="meeting-room-wrap">
  <div class="observable-module one">1
  </div>
  <div class="observable-module two">2
  </div>
  <div class="active-module three">3
  </div>
</div>
```