# Flexbox item breaking from flow

Tags: css, layout, css-float, flexbox

I'm creating a layout using flexbox and ran into a problem with a block not moving up below the previous block, but is being pushed down by the first block in the grid.

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="flex-wrap">

      <div class="flex-item flex-item-left">
        <div class="well">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-item flex-item-right">
        <div class="well">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-item flex-item-right">
        <div class="well">
          <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-item flex-item-right">
        <div class="well">
          <p>Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

 </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 1 66%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.flex-item-left {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex-item .well {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

I made a Flexbox vs. Float comparison here: http://codepen.io/coold78/full/yeagrp/

You might notice that I don't have all the right side content wrapped in a `div` tag (which would be a simple solution) but I want to see if I can create the same layout as the Float solution using flexbox without using the wrapper `div` for the right side content.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34070156/3597276

Comment: This solution seems to need specific box heights. I think I will need to wrap the right items in a parent `div`

Comment: The post I referred has both options: Using an inner wrapper, and maintaining the sibling relationship (no wrapper).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align flex items with different heights in the same container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069504/align-flex-items-with-different-heights-in-the-same-container)