# Re-arranging flex items for mobile and desktop view, without changing the HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material for my webpage. I have to show the same layout in different ways for desktop and mobile. Below are the layouts and the corresponding code:

**Mobile Layout**
[image: Mobile Layout]
**Mobile code**

```
<div layout="column" style="text-align: center;">
    <div flex-order="0">
        <div class="child-1">Child 1</div>
    </div>
    <div flex-order="1">
        <div class="child-2">Child 2</div>
    </div>
    <div flex-order="2">
        <div class="child-3">Child 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Desktop Layout**
[image: Desktop Layout]
**Desktop code**

```
<div layout="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div flex-order="0">
        <div class="child-2">Child 2</div>
    </div>
    <div flex>
        <div layout="column">
            <div flex-order="0">
                <div class="child-1">Child 1</div>
            </div>
            <div flex-order="1">
                <div class="child-3">Child 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.child-1, .child-2, .child-3 {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    background-color: gray; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.child-1, .child-3 {
    height: 20px;
}
.child-2 {
    height: 40px;
}
```

There is an obvious HTML code duplication to show the different layouts. Is there some way that these 2 layouts could be shown without duplicating the code?

Comment: Take a look at the answer posted as an alternative to mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34069504/3597276

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the answer. Although, I don't think it'll work for all the cases with different browsers and screen orientations(like, I need to have different heights for Child 1 and Child 3). Duplicating code might just be a necessary evil.

Comment: Are any of the desktop widths known, specifically Child2?

Comment: Well, if you're not averse to a bit of absolute positioning, then one version of HTML may still be possible. See my answer.

Comment: If the desktop widths are known this is pretty simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
   <div layout-sm="column" layout-gt-sm="row">
      <div hide-sm hide-xs style="background:grey" layout-margin> Child 2</div>
      <div layout="column" layout-align="space-around">
          <div  style="background:grey" layout-margin> Child 1</div>
          <div hide-gt-sm style="background:grey"layout-margin > Child 2</div>
          <div  style="background:grey" layout-margin> Child 3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPWorZ?editors=100)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean solution, using a simple html structure, the same for both mobile and desktop, and a media query to re-position the `child2` on bigger screens.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  position: relative;
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    background-color: gray; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}
.child2 {
    height: 40px;
}

@media screen and ( min-width: 500px) {
  .child2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 52px;
    width: 150px
  }
  .child1,
  .child3 {
    margin-left: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child3">Child 3</div>  
</div>
```