# Is it possible to skip learning Floats?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to skip learning floats because it's the old way of layout. I plan doing my layout with Flexbox. Is it possible to skip learning float and go straight to Flexbox?

edit: sorry for the stupid question im new.

Comment: lol.. no.. and if you understand flexbox, CSS columns and grid systems (all modern approaches to CSS layout) then you'll have no problem picking up floats.

Comment: It is better to read more and learn more and take it easy, it is not hard to learn. But about your question, please take a look at this question and maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648039/layout-possible-flexbox-vs-float-layout-with-multiple-columns-and-rows

Comment: I stay away from floats as much as possible, unless for something braindead easy like floating li. Float itself is not the problem, it's the clearfix hacks.
Let's say it like this: It is useful to understan float, but you can build any page without it one way or another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inevitably going to use floats one way or another. Not necessarily for layout, because as you've said it's outdated, but for things that floating was actually meant to do. Like [shifting images or figures or other interesting visual elements to the left or right with respect to some text](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats), as has been a staple of rich text documents as well as Web documents for decades. A different sort of "layout" to what modern web developers usually associate the word with.

Don't think of floating as some horrific abomination that you have to stay as far away from as possible. You just need to know when to use it correctly.